# Specify keys for mypy in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

Suppose I have some code like

```
def get_x(d: dict) -> int:
    d["x"]
```

However, I want to tell mypy that `d` should only contain certain keys (only the "x" key for example).  That way, if I make a mistake lower in the code trying to reference an invalid key of `d`, mypy will trigger an error.

My question is:

1. Is this possible? Can mypy validate dictionary keys?
2. If yes, how is this done? If no, is there a preferred workaround?

Comment: Something like [this](https://github.com/Michael0x2a/peps/blob/literal-types/pep-9999.rst)?

Comment: I think [TypedDict](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#typeddict) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ran into this problem too when trying to put some typing around AWS API Gateway/Lambda integration.

As pointed out by @Michael0x2a in the comments, [TypedDict](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/typed_dict.html) would seem to be the way to go, especially because it does not require any conversions yourself before passing into a function (a requirement for API responses, like you mentioned).

```
from mypy_extensions import TypedDict

DictWithOnlyX = TypedDict('DictWithOnlyX', {"x": str})

# error: Extra key 'y' for TypedDict "DictWithOnlyX@58"
dx1: DictWithOnlyX = { "y": 123 }

# error: Incompatible types (expression has type "int",
#        TypedDict item "x" has type "str")
dx2: DictWithOnlyX = { "x": 123 }

# GOOD!
dx3: DictWithOnlyX = { "x": "123" }
```

Should also note that, if dependencies are segregated between production and dev/test, then this makes `mypy` a **production** dependency.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways and assuming that your data structure must only have the same attributes, but they don't use dicts.

Instead of passing in a `dict`, you can use a namedtuple. Using a namedtuple, you can treat it as an object, but no new fields can be added either.

```
from collections import namedtuple

A = namedtuple("A", ["x", "y", "z"])

def get_x(d: A) -> int:
    d.x
```

Another way is to create a class and use the `__slot__` attribute. This also makes it so no new attributes can be accidentally inserted.

```
class A:
    __slot__ = ["x", "y", "z"]

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

Using the above methods,  you must define the fields at the very beginning.

Comment: Context: I'm testing APIs and the APIs are returning JSON. I don't want to have to convert each JSON into a namedtuple. I want some type checking in terms of what the client-side methods return. Is there a way for me to narrow down the dict type?

Comment: Nope. Don't think so. Python is an interpreted language. You can create a function that checks the existing keys with a set of keys and see if there are any that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I want to do this at the type level - I want mypy to find this mistake. I already have runtime checking but it’s not the same.